# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not working in if block

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code in Asp.Net MVC Razor view

```
            <p>
                     @if(dev.summary.Length > 250 )
                    {
                      <span> @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dev.summary)).ToString().Substring(0, 208) ... </span> <span> <a href="Development/Details/@dev.id">more</a></span>
                    }else
                    {
                       @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dev.summary))
                    }
                </p>
```

Problem is the code in the 'if' block does not remove the html tags in the content but the code in the 'else' block works fine. Please not that the "summary" content is from a CKeditor which is why we have the html tags.

Please any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think because you create a substring of the summary it creates a string that the decode method is not able to parse.

Comment: What if you remove `.ToString().Substring()`? Is it working correctly?

Comment: I am using substring to trim the length of the text if it is greater than 250 characters

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question this is what i did

```
            @if(dev.summary.Length > 250 )
               {
                      <span> @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dev.summary).ToString().Substring(0, 208)) ... </span> <span> <a href="Development/Details/@dev.id">more</a></span>
               }else
               {
                       @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dev.summary))
                }
```

I basically put the `ToString()` and `Substring()` methods inside the `@Html.Raw()`helper method. I hope someone finds it useful